# React Dev environment create a new Session

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, session

I have a simple NodeJS & React Webapp that works when I deploy the React build into NodeJS.

when I click login the server will check authorization and redirect to another page. when I try to run the webapp from the React build (port 3000) I notice that once logged in I have a new session and therefore fetching the data from the server (port 8080) will not work.

https://github.com/Yanipo5/MenuCreator

NodeJS - Login Api (Routing to url will work);

```
router.post('/',approveUserPassword, function(req, res){

  console.log(new Date() + ":" + req.sessionID)

  if(req.session.auth){
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/edit-menu'; 
    res.redirect(url);

  }
  });
function approveUserPassword(req, res, next) {

  let email = req.body.email;
  let psw = req.body.psw;
  let query = "SELECT id FROM Users "             +
              "WHERE email= '" + email + "' AND " +
              "password='" + psw + "'"            ;

  con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(result.length > 0){
      req.session.auth = true;
      req.session.rest_id = result[0].id;

    }else{
      req.session.auth = false;
    }

    next();
  });
}
```

---

**React** - will fail on port 3000, since the new session will not be authenticated.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let url ='http://localhost:8080/api/menu';
    fetch(url, {credentials: 'same-origin' })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            this.setState({data: json});
            console.log(json)
          })
  }
```

---

**api/menu**

```
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  console.log(new Date() + ":" + req.sessionID)

  if(!req.session.auth){
    res.json("no auth for menu");

    }else{
      next()

    }
};


router.get('/', checkAuth, function(req, res){

    let sql = "SELECT * FROM Menu_Items " +
                "WHERE rest_id=" + req.session.rest_id + ";";

    con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err){
        console.log(sql);
        throw err;
      }

      res.json(result);
    });

});
```

Here is the NodeJS log for the sessions (as you can see there are 2 unique):
Mon Nov 13 2017 19:21:59 GMT+0200 (IST):6tu0wi3Lt2RNEMD-SZHCzX2vJ0DljtHL
Mon Nov 13 2017 19:22:00 GMT+0200 (IST):JRBGJjxS109F3C_ghr3ggkQlcC5bapsE

Comment: https://github.com/Yanipo5/MenuCreator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local development server, and API, run on different ports. Due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) the browser will deny any requests that are not on the same domain, or port.

I've checked the repo and it's using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which means you should be able to set up a proxy. I've done this many times myself.

In `client-src/package.json` add the following line:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
```

This will proxy requests to the API. You can now make calls to your API like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let url ='http://localhost:3000/api/menu';
    fetch(url, {credentials: 'same-origin' })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({data: json});
        console.log(json)
      })
}
```

Comment: BugHunterUK! 
I'm amazed! spot on :)  (It's working of course)